# Opencart Javascript Pop Up Required Option Alert

Tags: javascript, popup, opencart, alert

I'm new in opencart. I need help to solve a problem related with Opencart product "Option Required Alert" on the product page.

I want a JavaScript alert box to appear if a client missed to select any required option from a product page.

Please help me solve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opencart 1.5.6.3

> Replace this line in htdocs\opencart1563\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl          line no 394 approx.

```
if (json['error']) {
  if (json['error']['option']) {
        for (i in json['error']['option']) {
      $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
          }
        }

 if (json['error']['profile']) 
  {$('select[name="profile_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['profile'] + '</span>'); }
}
```

> With

```
    if (json['error']) {
      if (json['error']['option']) {

    var abc = ' ';

        for (i in json['error']['option']) {
      $('#option-' + i).after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</span>');
      abc += ' ' + json['error']['option'][i] + ' ';
          }

    alert('->' + abc + '<-');

        }

  if (json['error']['profile']) 
  {$('select[name="profile_id"]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['profile'] + '</span>'); }
}
```

Opencart 2.0

> Replace this line in htdocs\opencart2\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\product.tpl          line no 460 apprx.

```
if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['option']) {
                    for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                        var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));                     
                        if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
                            element.parent().after('<div clas="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                        } else {
                            element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');              
                        }
                    }  
                }
```

> With

```
    if (json['error']) {
        if (json['error']['option']) {
  var abc = ' ';
            for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));                     
                if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
                    element.parent().after('<div clas="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
      abc += ' ' + json['error']['option'][i] + ' ';
                } else {
                    element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');              
      abc += ' ' + json['error']['option'][i] + ' ';
                }
            }  
   alert('->' + abc + '<-');
        }
```

Ask if you want some other function. or you don't understand it

Comment: Thanks "Salman Khan" but I forget to mention that I'm using opencart Version 1.5.6.3. can you please give suggestion for that version. thanks again

Comment: Also I'm using custom template.

Comment: Ok i W'll check for 1.5.6.3

Comment: That's really helpful. Thank you so much. Its works great with opencart Version 1.5.6.3. Even I applied this with my custom theme that's also works.